# a whole lot of errors that i cant understand while deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my backend server on heroku and later host my website. My build is done succesfully but while i think the problem is starting the project after its built.
here is my github link to project: https://github.com/lucifer01312/pinjanioverseas
and here are my errors

```
2020-10-13T20:40:22.649060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-10-13T20:40:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-10-13T20:40:24.887275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-10-13T20:40:24.932553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841067+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841090+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841091+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841091+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841091+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './fbconfig'
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841091+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841092+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/user.js
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841092+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/user-routes.js
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841092+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes.js
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841093+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841093+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841093+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841094+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/user.js:1:8)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841095+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:30)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841095+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841095+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19) {
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841096+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841097+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841097+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/user.js',
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841097+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/user-routes.js',
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841097+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/routes.js',
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841098+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/index.js'
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841098+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]
2020-10-13T20:40:24.841098+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module './fbconfig'` is your actual error message, the rest helps you find where in the code the error is coming from. Make sure that was commited to the codebase if it should have been (look online to confirm, unsure what it does). Heroku tends to be more strict in terms of what you can do than your local development  environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `fbconfig.js` file in your repository. Check the local directory of your project, maybe you forgot to push that file to GitHub.